# Possible to repeat an alias among different parameter sets in a powershell function?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have:

```
function f {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='x')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='x')]
        [Alias('a')]
        [int]$Apple,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='y')]
        [Alias('b')]
        [int]$Banana,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='x')]
        [Alias('b')]
        [int]$Cherry
    )
    
    "Apple $Apple"
    "Banana $Banana"
    "Cherry $Cherry"
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `f -Apple 1 -b 3` because including `Apple` means I'm certainly using Parameter Set `x`, but powershell complains that the alias b is declared multiple times.

Is it entirely impossible, or am I just missing a trick?

The non-trivial function I'm trying to write is a convenience wrapper for multiple external functions that have their own aliases, some of which can be the same for different named parameters, but the set of mandatory parameters would never be ambiguous.

Comment: Alias `b` is indeed defined for both Parameter Banana and Cherry, so when using that alias, it is impossible to make the distinction between the two.

Comment: `f -b 1` on its own can only be valid for parameterset `y` because parameterset `x` requires parameter `Apple`. Similarly, `f -b 1 -a 2` must be parameterset `x` because `y` does not take parameter `a` for `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work using regular params, but I found a workaround by defining `Banana` and `Cherry` as [dynamic params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#dynamic-parameters). This way the alias `b` is only defined once, so PowerShell won't complain.

```
function f {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='x')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='x')]
        [Alias('a')]
        [int]$Apple
    )

    DynamicParam {
        # If param 'Apple' exists, define dynamic param 'Cherry',
        # else define dynamic param 'Banana', both using alias 'b'.

        if( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Apple') ) { 
            $paramName = 'Cherry'
            $paramSetName = 'x' 
        } else { 
            $paramName = 'Banana'
            $paramSetName = 'y' 
        }

        $aliasName = 'b'

        $parameterAttribute = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
            ParameterSetName = $paramSetName
            Mandatory = $true
        }

        $aliasAttribute = [System.Management.Automation.AliasAttribute]::new( $aliasName )

        $attributeCollection = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
        $attributeCollection.Add( $parameterAttribute )
        $attributeCollection.Add( $aliasAttribute )            

        $dynParam = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            $paramName, [Int32], $attributeCollection
        )

        $paramDictionary = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
        $paramDictionary.Add($paramName, $dynParam)

        $paramDictionary
    }    

    process {
        "--- Parameter Set '$($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)' ---"

        if( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Apple') ) { 
            "Apple $Apple"
        }
        if( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Banana') ) { 
            # Dynamic params require special syntax to read
            $Banana = $PSBoundParameters.Banana
            "Banana $Banana"
        }
        if( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Cherry') ) { 
            # Dynamic params require special syntax to read
            $Cherry = $PSBoundParameters.Cherry
            "Cherry $Cherry"
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling the function:**

```
f -Apple 1 -b 3

f -b 2
```

**Output:**

```text
--- Parameter Set 'x' ---
Apple 1
Cherry 3
--- Parameter Set 'y' ---    
Banana 2
```